# How do I access to my wordpress pages?

Tags: wordpress

I know wordpress store the page content inside the database. If I wanna to add content and some programming content into the page, how do I do it? Other than going to wordpress dashboard > page > all pages, is there any way to access the page file so that I can directly write the codes to it?

Comment: Why do you want to "directly write the codes to it"?

Comment: can you elaborate more on what "codes" you want to put ? You also have an HTML view inside the editor ..

Comment: I'm actually using Wordpress for business website purpose. I may need to link the registration page to my database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use you webhost's file manager, or your own FTP client to modify the files that wordpress is made of. Though I recommend against this; if you want to do work beyond just editing the appearance, you should design your site from scratch. If appearances are all, search for a tutorial on making wordpress themes, then apply your shiny new theme.

Answer (score 0):

You'll use page.php or page-template.php file under `wp-content/themes/yourthemeName/`
That way you will change the file template....